# Regex in Chef directory resource

Tags: chef-infra

Is it possible to do something like the following in chef? I need to find a set of directories using a regular expression.

```
directory "/regex/"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate with an exemple on what you want to achieve ? I guess you can with plain ruby and looping ot create each resource. But it's a guess only...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Tensibai, you can use a bit of Ruby code to get something like this:

```
Dir['/foo/*'].each do |path|
  directory path do
    owner 'me'
  end
end
```

There are a few issues though. The big one is that this will run the glob (not a regex, but shell globs are more common for this) at recipe compile time, so it won't pick up things created within the Chef run. The more abstract issue is that the directory resource is generally how you create directories, so I'm not really sure what the use case is here beyond possibly chown'ing directories created by a vendor install script or similar.